# Computer booting straight to windows (skips grub)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

My computer boots straight into windows instead of starting grub at startup, i tried to reinstall grub, tried to run boot-repair, also tried efibootmgr. I want my computer booting into grub instead of needing to click f9 repeatedly at startup. After trying to change windows files into grubs, windows stopped booting so changed back to windows and now it works but grub boots straight into ubuntu.

Comment: did you reinstall grub, or not? If yes, then did you set it as default in your BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: It started booting straight to windows after i tried to update to windows 10, which didn't work. Since then I need to open the boot option and then go to grub

Comment: See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html) for information on this type of problem. (That page is part of my rEFInd documentation, but the same principles apply to GRUB.) Using `efibootmgr` *appropriately* should fix the problem, but you need to determine the correct boot order *for you* and then apply it with `sudo efibootmgr -o ###,###,...` to set the right boot order.